# Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Xcode with C code

Tags: ios, c, xcode, multithreading

I am using Xcode to code in C language. I am getting strange error.

If ranges(`height2, width2`) of for loops are around 500,600 code is working fine. BUT if I change ranges more than 800 then it gives me following error.

> "Thread 1: EXE_BAD_ACCESS(CODE - 2, address = 07x33434...)"

```
for (int i = 0 ; i <height2 ; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0 ; j< width2 ; j++)
    {
        float height_Frac_Idx = i*scale_h;
        float width_Frac_Idx = j*scale_w;
        int height_idx, width_idx;
        height_idx = (int) height_Frac_Idx;
        width_idx =  (int) width_Frac_Idx;
        float del_h = height_Frac_Idx - height_idx;
        float del_w = width_Frac_Idx - width_idx;


        img_op[i][j] = (img_IP[height_idx][width_idx])*(1 - del_h)*(1-del_w) + (img_IP[height_idx+1][width_idx])*(del_h)*(1-del_w) + (img_IP[height_idx][width_idx+1])*(1 - del_h)*(del_w) + (img_IP[height_idx+1][width_idx+1])*(del_h)*(del_w);            

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know C, but I guess that img_op is an array with an array, maybe you're going out of bounds with 800+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Thread 1: EXE_BAD_ACCESS(CODE - 2, address = 07x33434...)"

This error come when when you accessing the unallocated or more that allocated memory in code.

Looking your code and explanation i can guess  that you probably  accessing some more memory in case of  `img_op[][] or img_IP[][]` array.

Also try Enabling NSZombies
Very easy to enable:

1. Double click your executable in the “Executables” in XCode
2. Open “Arguments” tab
3. In “Variables to be set in the environment” (that’s the list at the
   bottom, be careful which one you edit) click the “+” button and for
   name of the variable enter “NSZombieEnabled” and for value “YES”